# 24 bit deep wav file generator

Tags: python-2.7, audio, wav, wave

is it posible to generate wav file in python with 24bit deep and sample width 4, not 3 (3x8=24). The idea is to have 32bit deep, so that sample width of 4 (4x8=32) can be made, but i would try to make upper bits all ones (1), so that it looks like 24bit deep.
Im open to suggestions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. The trick was to make wav file the same way as you would make it for 32 bit depth, but set LOWER(not upper) 8 bits(LSBs) to zeros. So in hex format you would have 00 xx xx 00 xx xx ... where xx are some hex numbers.